# Why is react 'stl-viewer' not loading my stl file served by my private custom python flask api

Tags: reactjs

If this is not the right place to ask this, please let me know.

Some Background: I have a python / flask API that will serve relevant data and an STL file on request. CORS is enabled as required. With that server running i have tested by placing the link to download the file in the address bar. That successfully downloads the correct file. Additionally I placed the link in the 'react-stl-obj-viewer' library and see my STL model there as expected. So I am certain that the custom API is working properly.

probably not useful - but relevant API background code:

```
    # @login_required
    def get_model(part_id):
        part = Repo().find_part(part_id)
        if part:
            try:
                file_path = '\\'.join(part["File_Path"].split('\\')[0:-1])
                print(file_path)
                print(part["Name"])
                return send_from_directory(file_path, part["Name"])
            except:
                json_response({'error': f"Failed to complete request for STL model {part_id}"}, 405)
        else:
            return json_response({'error': 'project not found'}, 404)
```

The problem: With the server running for the python API and the react app, i instantiate the following component multiple times.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {stlLink: "http://localhost:5000/parts/models/part.stl"}
  }

  render(){
    return ( 
      <div style={{width: 200, height:200, color: "#eb4034"}} >
       
       <STLViewer
          url={this.state.stlLink}
          width={400}
          height={400}
          modelColor='#B92C2C'
          backgroundColor='#EAEAEA'
          rotate={true}
          orbitControls={true}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

On every instance there is a loading animation - good. But i cannot see any traffic on the API - Bad. So my parts never get loaded into the viewer.

I have tried changing the method for the request in the server from GET to POST, nothing changed. I am unsure what else to try because this feels like something that should 'just work'. Thats why im here :) does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as you. Try out this code, It's working for me...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import STLViewer from '../../src/STLViewer';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: '#FF0000',
      model: undefined
    };

    this.clickBlue = this.clickBlue.bind(this);
    this.clickRed = this.clickRed.bind(this);
  }

  clickBlue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ color: '#0000FF' });
  }

  clickRed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ color: '#FF0000' });
  }

  onChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { files } = target;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.setState({ model: reader.result });
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="image-file" type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <STLViewer
          modelColor={this.state.color}
          lights={[[0.5, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1]]}
          rotate={true}
          model={this.state.model}
        />
        <button onClick={this.clickRed}>red</button>
        <button onClick={this.clickBlue}>blue</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```